.NET 6 Application fails after windows updates with Hostpolicy.dll missing
I have a .NET 6 application that operates on the .NET 6.0.11 runtime. Occasionally, when Windows updates occur, they install newer versions of .NET 6, such as .NET 6.0.26. Following these updates, my application fails to execute.
Upon reviewing the event viewer logs, I've encountered the following error. What might be causing this problem? How can I safeguard my application from being impacted by these Windows updates? Any assistance would be greatly valued.
Description: A .NET application failed.
Application: MyApp.exe
Path: C:\Test\MyApp.exe
Message: Cannot use file stream for [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.26\Microsoft.NETCore.App.deps.json]: No such file or directory
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.26'.


Did you check this out?

If you are using the hosting bundle for example, then windows update will replace the installed tuntime. That means, any app needs to restart after such an update. That's by design it seems, at least according to similar github issues about this topic.

@DenisMicheal my scenario is different. MyApp.exe when it is running on .NET 6.0.11 runtime, it just works fine but as soon as when the Windows update happens the .NET 6.0.26 runtime gets installed post this installation when MyApp.exe tries to run it is running into 'hostpolicy.dll' missing issue. Not sure what is the reason for this issue

@MichaC I understand the windows update will replace the installed runtime with the higher version. After restarting my application it is encountering "Hostpolicy.dll" missing issue with higher version. The only Workaround is to un-install and re-install the higher version of .NET 6 runtime again to make application to run. But, the question here is: why would windows update is causing this issue?

good question. if you have a good example which can maybe even reproduced then I'd strongly suggest to log that on github: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues. There are already some similar issues but I don't think any windows update related
